# Can I deserialize a JAX-RS Response?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I've written a JAX-RS API that looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("findallbyname")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
Response findAllByName(String payload);
```

Where `Response` is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`. The `entity` property of the `Response` is a `List<String>`, so this response just returns the JSON serialization of a list of strings.

In a separate app, I'm calling the API like so (using an http-remoting library [found here](https://github.com/palantir/http-remoting)):

```
Service service = JaxRsClient.builder().build(Service.class, "<user-agent>", "<uri>");
Response response = service.findAllByName("some string");
```

However, I get this error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
    Can not construct instance of javax.ws.rs.core.Response: 
        abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
        at [Source: java.io.BufferedReader@2ef14fe; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Ok, this seems like a straightforward object serde problem -- it looks like since `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` is an abstract type, it can't deserialize on the client side (the request goes through and comes back with status 200, according to the server request logs).

My question is, since my original API was written to respond with the abstract `Response` object type, am I out of luck when it comes to deserializing the response object I get on the client side? I *can* change the API, but I wanted to ask and see if there was a better way to solve this deserialization problem on the client side first.

Comment: May I know if you find out the answer finally?

Comment: Hey @Matt, I ended up just changing the API to return my `CustomObject` type, and modified the client to receive that same type. Jaxrs automatically handled serde on both ends.

Comment: FWIW, I used the Immutables library to generate my POJOs, and it makes serde over the wire a breeze. https://immutables.github.io/